# react-data-table-component with nested tables

Tags: node.js, reactjs, xlsm, nested-table, react-data-table-component

I am using react-data-table-component in a node/react page. I have 2 data sets, `List` and `ListNested`.

`list` is a collections of document data (xlsm to be specific) that has the most recent version of the document on each row.

`listNested` is a similar data set, but contains all previous versions of each record in `list` (if they exist).

I have my parent table defined as:

```
return(    
  <DataTable
    title="Documents"
    columns={columns}
    data={list}
    pagination={true}
    fixedHeader={true}
    keyField="document_id"
    striped={true}
    highlightOnHover={true}
    noDataComponent=<div className="loader">
      <Loader
        type="Oval"
        color="#005ea2"
        height={100}
        width={100} />
    </div>
    persistTableHead={true}
    defaultSortField="updated_at"
    defaultSortAsc={false}
    overflowY={true}

    expandableRows
    expandableRowDisabled={row => row.disabled}
    expandableRowsComponent={<ExpanableComponent />}

  />
);
```

and my ExpandableComponent defined as:

```
const ExpanableComponent = ({listNested}) =>
  <DataTable
    columns={columnsNested}
    data={listNested}
    pagination={true}
    fixedHeader={true}
    keyField="doc_name"
    striped={true}
    highlightOnHover={true}
    noDataComponent=<div>No previous versions of this document were found.</div>
    persistTableHead={true}
    defaultSortField="updated_at"
    defaultSortAsc={false}
    overflowY={true}
  />;
```

the documentation [[Here]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component#14-installation) does not clearly define this type of nesting. I tried using the `doc_name` attribute as the `keyField`, but it doesn't work properly. The nested data shows up in the parent table instead of nested table, but the nested table headings DO show up in the nested row.

In the picture below, rows 2 and 3 are coming from the `listNested` data set in the `ExpandableComponent` and should be nested under row 1. however, row 1 shows an empty data set (circled).

[image]

I verified the lists both have the data I want them to, I am just stuck on how to stick the second list into the nested section.

Comment: Did you got the awnser?

Comment: @AndersonSilva strange enough if you put {data} as your first argument in the expandable component you get the row data so yes it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

To make this work you have to call your prop exactly `data`, not `listNested`, like this:

```js
const ExpanableComponent = ({data, ...props}) =>
  <DataTable data={data} {...props}/>
```

By the way, it even works with calling itself as an `expandableRowsComponent`.

```js
export default function MyDataTable({data, ...props}) {
    return <Datatable 
        expandableRows
        expandableRowsComponent={<MyDataTable className="ml-3"/>}
        noTableHead={!!data}
        noHeader={!!data}
        {...props}
    />
}
```

To use this component you don't have to use prop `data`. Two latter props indicate that if  data is `undefined` (since [] is still truthy), then the table doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 1):

I added {data} argument as the first argument in the props of expandable component and it worked for me.